# \copy PSQL command not working with POINT(...) geometry type

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have been trying to find the solution for quite a while...

The `\copy` command in Postgres is not working with the datatype `geography(Point,4326)`.

The error it gives is:

```
ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "ST" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry
CONTEXT:  COPY data2, line 1, column loc: "ST_GeomFromText('POINT(62.0271954112486 87.9028962135794)')"
```

Here is the command I am using:

```
\copy data2(loc,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9,d10) from 'fake_data.csv' delimiter ',' csv;
```

I have **inserted** into the table using the exact same format as the csv file and it has been successful. It seems it is just something with the `\copy` command that doesn't like the format.

Here is an example row from my csv file:

```
ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT(28.872109890126964 160.10529558104636)'),24.237968,129.512386,227.032799,27.644993,60.959401,25.178026,201.229746,34.178728,250.975993,3.635878
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `COPY` to process an expression like this. Rather, the file has to contain the *extended well-known binary* (EWKB) format, which is what you get when you run

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT(81.5538863138809 42.72341176405514)');
```

In your case, the CVS file will have to look like this:

```
0101000020E61000000C9D009842DF3C403DA0D6945E036440,24.237968,129.512386,227.032799,27.644993,60.959401,25.178026,201.229746,34.178728,250.975993,3.635878
```

Comment: Hi @laurenz , thanks for the quick response. I changed it to EWKB format and ran the same command but got the same error message unfortunately. Did I misinterpret your answer?

Comment: Please edit the question and show your CSV file and your `\copy` command.

Comment: okay I updated the question. I was not sure if you meant that `SELECT` should be in the file so I tried including it and not including it before `ST_GeomFromEWKT...`. Both failed. The error when the csv file began with `SELECT` was the exact same as in the question except that the `HINT` was `SE` instead of `ST`.

Comment: Ok, I have added how your CSV file should look.

Comment: thanks again for all your help. So my confusion is how to get the CSV file to look like your example above. This is my understanding of how the process should go, please correct me if I am wrong. Create a CSV file that looks like my example row above. Use the `\copy` command to insert all of the rows into a table which will automatically create a geometry (in my example called `loc`).

Comment: Sounds right. If it's not feasible for you to convert the data to this format, maybe you could use `INSERT` instead. That allows you use an expression.